# I can fetch the json data but I can't display it in HTML (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    </head>

    <body>
            <table class="table table-stripped">
                <tbody id="data">
    
                </tbody>
            </table> 
    
    
        <script>
            fetch("wig.json").then(
                res=>{
                    res.json().then(
                        data=>{
                            console.log(data);
                            if(data.length > 0){
                                var tmp = '';
                                data.forEach((u)=>{
                                    tmp +="<tr>";
                                    tmp += "<td>"+u.Name+"</td>";
                                    tmp += "<td>"+u.Oprice+"</td></tr>";
                                })
                                document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = tmp;
                            };
                        }
                    )
                }
            )
        </script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

I can fetch the local json data and I can see all my json data in the console.
Yet. I can't display it using table and there is no any error statement shown.
Can someone help me to fix this problem.
I reference the code from:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WMQ2sq1dw6Y&t=230s

Comment: Please add your console log results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have created example for you but different source so i used json placeholder as source but the same approach of your code

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(res => {
  return res.json();
}).then(data => {
  console.log(data);
  if (data.length > 0) {
    let tmp = "";
    
    data.forEach(u => {
      tmp += `
        <tr>
          <td>${u.title}</td>
          <td>${u.body}</td>
        </tr>
      `
    });
    
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = tmp;
  }
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-stripped">
  <tbody id="data">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You can use template literals to format your html string easily. I think the error on your code is the syntax near `res.json` you forgot to nest the brackets correctly.

If still not working check your data may be the casing of your json keys is not correct.

Comment: This should be the json file problem
Problem solved thx!!!!!!